# How to calculate error percentages whilst grouping by each condition

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr

Here is an example of my dataframe

```
dat <- structure(list(numbers = c(6, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4), condition = c("controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue"
), key = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), accuracy = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    RTs = c(0.384226126328, 0.467277575192, 0.467324494844, 0.467498610738, 
    0.483966675317, 0.484211170689), participant = c(1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1), hand = c("left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
    "left"), parity = c("even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
    "even")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

My experiment has 3 conditions within the condition column - controltrue, exptrue and explie. I would like to calculate the percentage of errors for each condition. The accuracy column denotes whether a response was correct (1) or an error (0). Is there a way to calculate the percentage of errors whilst grouping by the condition?

I feel like this can be done within dplyr syntax. So far I have summarised the number of errors and correct trials per condition:

```
errors <- dat %>%
  dplyr::group_by(condition, accuracy) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(acc_num = n())

errors

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   condition [3]
  condition   accuracy acc_num
  <chr>       <fct>      <int>
1 controltrue 0            152
2 controltrue 1           2887
3 explie      0            865
4 explie      1           5190
5 exptrue     0            599
6 exptrue     1          11543
```

However I am now not sure how to divide the accuracy 1 by accuracy 0 and multiple by 100 to get a percentage within the dplyr syntax. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you need `dat %>% group_by(condition) %>% mutate(Perc = sum(accuracy != 0)/sum(.$accuracy != 0))`

Comment: Well, given where you are, I think `%>% group_by(condition) %>% mutate(perc = acc_num / sum(acc_num))` would actually just work after the `summarise` line. Not sure if it will want an `ungroup()` in there first.

Comment: Thank you @Adam this is good solution!